# Difference between @Mock, @MockBean and Mockito.mock()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

When creating tests and mocking dependencies, what is the difference between these three approaches?

1. @MockBean:

   ```
   @MockBean
   MyService myservice;
   ```
2. @Mock:

   ```
   @Mock
   MyService myservice;
   ```
3. Mockito.mock()

   ```
   MyService myservice = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
   ```

Answer (score 317, accepted):

**Plain Mockito library**

```
import org.mockito.Mock;
...
@Mock
MyService myservice;
```

and

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
...
MyService myservice = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
```

come from the Mockito library and are functionally equivalent. 
They allow to mock a class or an interface and to record and verify behaviors on it.

The way using annotation is shorter, so preferable and often preferred.

---

Note that to enable Mockito annotations during test executions, the
`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` static method has to be called.
To avoid side effect between tests, it is advised to do it before each test execution :

```
@Before 
public void initMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Another way to enable Mockito annotations is annotating the test class with `@RunWith` by specifying the `MockitoJUnitRunner` that does this task and also other useful things :

```
@RunWith(org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public MyClassTest{...}
```

---

**Spring Boot library wrapping Mockito library**

This is indeed a [Spring Boot class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html):

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
...
@MockBean
MyService myservice;
```

The class is included in the `spring-boot-test` library.

It allows to add Mockito mocks in a Spring `ApplicationContext`.
If a bean, compatible with the declared class exists in the context, it **replaces** it by the mock.
If it is not the case, it **adds** the mock in the context as a bean.

Javadoc reference :

> Annotation that can be used to add mocks to a Spring
>   ApplicationContext.
>
> ...
>
> If any existing single bean of the same type defined in the context
>   will be replaced by the mock, if no existing bean is defined a new one
>   will be added.

---

**When use classic/plain Mockito and when use `@MockBean` from Spring Boot ?**

Unit tests are designed to test a component in isolation from other components and unit tests have also a requirement : being as fast as possible in terms of execution time as these tests may be executed each day dozen times on the developer machines.

Consequently, here is a simple guideline :

As you write a test that doesn't need any dependencies from the Spring Boot container, the classic/plain Mockito is the way to follow : it is fast and favors the isolation of the tested component.
If your test needs to rely on the Spring Boot container **and** you want also to add or mock one of the container beans : `@MockBean` from Spring Boot is the way.

---

**Typical usage of Spring Boot `@MockBean`**

As we write a test class annotated with `@WebMvcTest` (web test slice).

[The Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests) summarizes that very well :

> Often `@WebMvcTest` will be limited to a single controller and used in
>   combination with `@MockBean` to provide mock implementations for
>   required collaborators.

Here is an example :

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(FooController.class)
public class FooControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private FooService fooServiceMock;

    @Test
    public void testExample() throws Exception {
         Foo mockedFoo = new Foo("one", "two");

         Mockito.when(fooServiceMock.get(1))
                .thenReturn(mockedFoo);

         mvc.perform(get("foos/1")
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string("one two"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Will using @MockBean create a copy of the bean and inject it to the ApplicationContext? Or will the mocked bean have all its methods as null? If all the methods are null can I stub them like I can do using @Mock?

Comment: As explained, using `@MockBean` will replace the bean in the application context if a bean declaring the same type is already defined in your Spring configuration. And the injection is performed in the class where you declare  `@MockBean.` The DI mechanisms works in this way : you register an object in the DI context and then you can inject the object referenced in the Spring context in a specific class. You don't inject an object in the DI context.

Comment: I am following but how come the service class have 0 % coverage?

Comment: The problem with `@MockBean` is that it doesn't work with `Mockito.verify`

Answer (score 28):

At the end its easy to explain. If you just look into the javadocs of the annotations you will see the differences:

@Mock:  (`org.mockito.Mock`)

> Mark a field as a mock.

> - Allows shorthand mock creation.
> - Minimizes repetitive mock creation code.
> - Makes the test class more readable.
> - Makes the verification error easier to read because the field name is used to identify the mock.

@MockBean:  (`org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean`)

> Annotation that can be used to add mocks to a Spring ApplicationContext. Can be used as a class level annotation or on fields in either `@Configuration` classes, or test classes that are `@RunWith` the SpringRunner.

> Mocks can be registered by type or by bean name. Any existing single bean of the same type defined in the context will be replaced by the mock, if no existing bean is defined a new one will be added.

> When `@MockBean` is used on a field, as well as being registered in the application context, the mock will also be injected into the field.

Mockito.mock()

> Its just the representation of a `@Mock`.

Comment: Let's not forget that @Mock requires the MockitoRunner or initMocks being called manually.

Comment: Is the only difference between `@MockBean` and `@Mock` that one will inject the mock into the `Spring ApplicationContext` and the other won't?

Comment: @Doug You summarized it well but one needs to remember that MockBean is part of Spring Boot

Comment: To use `@MockBean` you would need to annotate the class with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`. However for using `@Mock` you can use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and call initMocks() as @Florian-schaetz mentioned. `@Mock` will work with SpringRunner as well but with the added overhead of loading the applicationContext

Answer (score 4):

Mocktio.mock() :-

1. Will create a mock object of either class or interface. We can use
   this mock to stub the return values and verify if they are called.
2. We must use the `when(..)` and `thenReturn(..)` methods for mock objects
   whose class methods will be invoked during test case execution.

`@Mock` :-

1. This is shorthand for `mock()` method so it is preferable and often
   used.
2. Both `mock()` and `@Mock` are functionally equivalent.
3. Easier to identify the problem in mock failure as name of the field appears in the error message.

To enable the Mockito annotation during test execution we need to call the `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` method but this method is deprecated instead we can call - `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)`. In order to avoid the side effects it is advised to call this method before test case executions.

Another way to enable the Mockito annotations is by annotating the test class with `@RunWith` by specifying the MockitoJUnitRunner that does this task and also other useful things.

`@MockBean` :-
It is used to add the mock objects into spring application context.
This mock will replace the existing bean of same type in application
context. If no bean is available, then new bean will be added. This
is useful in integration test case.

When we write a test case that doesn't need any dependencies from the Spring Boot container, the classic/plain Mockito is used and it is fast and favors the isolation of the tested component.

If our test case needs to rely on the Spring Boot container and want to add or mock one of the container beans then `@MockBean` is used.

Comment: This is the more simple and clear explaining IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Shortly we can say for `@MockBean` annotation: The mock will substitute any existing bean of the same type within the application context, and if no bean of the same type is defined, a new one will be included. This annotation proves valuable during **`integration tests`** when it becomes necessary to mock a specific bean, such as an **`external service`**.