# Why is there difference between @Mock and Mockito.mock(UriInfo.class)?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, java-ee-6

Mockito.mock and @Mock are supposed to [do the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200720/difference-between-mock-mockbean-and-mockito-mock). Curiously enough, this does not seem to be the case when mocking [UriInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html).  In my unit test using JUnit4, the code below works:

```
private UriInfo uriInfo = Mockito.mock(UriInfo.class);
```

whereas this raised error of "parameter uriInfo not set" upon running the test:

```
@Mock
private UriInfo uriInfo;
```

Comment: if you are using `@Mock` , you need to initialize mocks using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` Do you have this?

Comment: If you are using Mockito mocking annotations, you need to call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`  This is often done in a method that is marked with the @Before annotation.

Comment: From your link `Note that to enable Mockito annotations during test executions, the MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) static method has to be called.`

Comment: That is wild! I do have that @RunWith statement.

Answer (score 2):

Have you done mock initialization?

```
@Before
public void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Or you can use a special runner on your test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

Where do you use your mocked `urlInfo`? Did you specify a mocked implementation for it's methods? For example,

```
when(urlInfo.getPath()).thenReturn("some/path");
when(urlInfo.toString()).thenReturn("some/path");
```

Comment: Yes, I did use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` to have mockito run the test.

Comment: uriInfo is passed as an object, with no method invoked. The class under test does `extends` another class. But my question here is why @Mock differs from its alternative. It almost appears that @Mock returned null, whereas Mockito.mock() returned a non-null value.

Comment: are you sure that it differs? can you see `null` in debugger after initialization?

Comment: I am certain of the `null` because in the Failure Trace I can see the message unique for the Exception thrown when uriInfo is null (inside the parent class which my class extends).

Comment: @TreefishZhang maybe it's not the `urlInfo` itself is null. Check it. Maybe one of it's methods is used - and **all** methods of a mock return `null` by default.