# How to substitute Mockito in place to stub a class in JUnit Test Java

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, stub

I am trying to substitute the correct use of Mockito, during a test session by JUnit, in place of to stub a class.
Unfortunately on web there are a lot of tutorials regarding Mockito but, less for the stub approach, and I would like to learn this technique.

This test is made by Mockito:

```
 @Test
public void addWrongNewUserSpaceInUsername() throws Exception {

    when(userValidator.isValidUsername(user.getUsername())).thenReturn(false);

    try {
        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/register")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(asJsonString(user)
                        ));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.assertTrue(e.getCause() instanceof UsernameNotValidException);
    }
}
```

To clarify these are the classes involved:

1) Controller

```
   @RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    RepositoryUserDB repositoryUserDB;

    @Autowired
    UserValidator userValidator;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user) {


        if (userValidator.isValidUsername(user.getUsername())) {

            if(!userValidator.isValidPassword(user.getPassword())){
                throw new PasswordNotValidException();
            }

            if(userValidator.isValidDateOfBirth(user.getDateOfBirth()) == false){
                throw new DOBNotValidException();
            }

            // se lo user e' gia' presente
            if (repositoryUserDB.getUserByUsername(user.getUsername()) == null) {
                return repositoryUserDB.createUser(user);
            }
            throw new UsernameAlreadyExistException();
        } else throw new UsernameNotValidException();

    }
}
```

2)Interface of repo:

```
public interface RepositoryUserDB {

    User getUserByUsername(String username);

    User createUser(User user);
}
```

3)Repo:

```
@Component

    public class MemoryUserDB implements RepositoryUserDB{

        Map<String, User> repo;

        public MemoryUserDB() {
            this.repo = new HashMap<>();
        }

        @Override
        public  User getUserByUsername(String username) {
            return repo.get(username);
        }

        @Override
        public User createUser(User user) {
            repo.put(user.getUsername(),user);
            return repo.get(user.getUsername());
        }
    }
```

4) Validator:

```
   @Component
public class UserValidator {

    public boolean isValidUsername(String username) {
        return username.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    }

    public boolean isValidPassword(String pwd) {
        if (pwd == null)
            return false;
        return pwd.matches("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d){4,}.+$");
    }

    public boolean isValidDateOfBirth(String DOB) {
        return DOB.matches("^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\\/|-|\\.)31)\\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\\/|-|\\.)(?:29|30)\\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$|^(?:0?2(\\/|-|\\.)29\\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])\\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$");
    }
}
```

5)ResEntityExceptionHandler

```
    @ControllerAdvice
public class RestEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(UsernameNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, reason = "username wrong")
    public void handleUsernameException() {
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(UsernameAlreadyExistException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "the username is already presents")
    public void handleUsername() {
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(PasswordNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, reason = "password wrong")
    public void handlePasswordException() {
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(DOBNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, reason = "Date Of Birth wrong")
    public void handleDOBException(){
    }

}
```

Comment: how do you inject the validation into the controller?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski:  by a class using ControllerAdvice. Do you need it?

Comment: would be useful to see the full set-up for the test

Comment: ok I will edit my question and add the class

Comment: @MaciejKowalski: done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, for you use case, the stub approach should be rather simple to do.
But as you rely on a Spring Boot Test that uses the Spring beans container, things are really harder to setup as you should find a way to inject the mocked bean in the container to replace the actual bean : `UserValidator`. 
Mocks in Spring Boot test rely usually on [Spring Boot `MockBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans).
It is not a mockito mock but not very far.
To understand differences with Mockito mocks, you may refer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200720/difference-between-mock-mockbean-and-mockito-mock/44200907).

Using a framework gives many features out of the box, but also limits yourself as you want to bypass the framework features.

---

Supposing that you didn't perform an integration test with Spring Boot, but a real unit test (so without the Spring boot container), things could be performed in this way.

Instead of mocking `UserValidator.isValidUsername()`, you define a custom implementation of `UserValidator` that stubs the method return as expected in your test.
Finally, what Mockito or any mock framework does for you.

So here is the stub class :

```
public class UserValidatorStub extends UserValidator {

    private String expectedUsername;
    private boolean isValidUsername;

    public UserValidatorStub(String expectedUsername, boolean isValidUsername){
          this.expectedUsername = expectedUsername;
          this.isValidUsername = isValidUsername;
    }
    public boolean isValidUsername(String username) {
        if (username.equals(expectedUsername)){
           return isValidUsername;
        }
        // as fallback, it uses the default implementation but you may return false or null as alternative
       return super.isValidUsername(username);
    }

}
```

It accepts a constructor to store the expected arguments passed to the stubbed method and the stubbed result to return.

Now, here how your test could be written :

```
 @Test
public void addWrongNewUserSpaceInUsername() throws Exception {

    // inject the mock in the class under test
    UserController userController = new UserController(new UserValidatorStub(user.getUsername(), false));
    try {
        userController.createUser(user);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.assertTrue(e.getCause() instanceof UsernameNotValidException);
    }
}
```

Note that the example relies on constructor injection in `UserController` to set the dependencies.

Comment: Your intervention has been really precious.

Comment: Your question is really interesting. In some specific cases, I stub instead of mocking because mocking features lack some things to implement  the expected acceptance test. And unfortunately, things are sometimes very hard to setup because of the framework approach. So, I loved your question !

Comment: Thank you @davidxxx, I am trying to be more confidence in Java language. I am only a Junior Developer :)
and I have to learn to be efficient.