# UnsatisfiedDependencyException in a @WebMvcTest test class

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-test, spring-rest

My unit tests fail after I added @Service to the controller.
The project is Spring-boot v 2.0.1.RELEASE. I've spent many hours trying to find the answer but no luck. The test worked before I added @Service annotation and my service class has a repository in it.

Stack trace:

> 2018-04-24 12:57:12.487  WARN 940 --- [           main]
>   o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'fleetController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'uk.co.vw.lead.service.ContactUsService'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Controller:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = VERSION, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public class FleetController {
public static final String VERSION = "1.0";

@Autowired
private ContactUsService service;

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(final WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
    webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(NatureOfEnquiryEnum.class, new  NatureOfEnquiryEnumConverter());
    webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(FleetSizeEnum.class, new  FleetSizeEnumConverter());
}

@PostMapping(value = "/fleet/contact-us")
public ResponseEntity contactUs(@Valid ContactUsDTO formDTO) {
    service.createForm(formDTO);
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}

@PostMapping(value = "/fleet/request-demo")
public ResponseEntity requestDemo(@Valid RequestDemoDTO demoDTO) {



    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class ContactUsServiceImpl implements ContactUsService {

@Autowired
private FleetRepository repository;

@Override
public void createForm(ContactUsDTO formDTO) {
    ContactUsForm form = populateContactUsForm(formDTO);
    repository.save(form);
}
```

}

Test class:

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@WebMvcTest(FleetController.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class FleetControllerTest {

private final String CONTACT_US_URL = "/fleet/contact-us";

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private FleetRepository repository;

@Autowired
private ContactUsService service;


@Test
public void contactUsSuccessTest() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform( post("/" + VERSION + CONTACT_US_URL)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
                    .param("firstname", "John")
                    .param("lastname", "Doe")
                    .param("company", "Skynet")
                    .param("emailAddress", "john.connor@sky.net")
                    .param("telephone", "020 8759 4294")
                    .param("natureOfEnquiry", "new")
                    .param("comments", "some comments")
                    .param("recaptchaResponse", "success"))
            .andExpect(status().isNoContent());
}

@Test
public void contactUsMissingRequiredFieldsTest() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform( post("/1.0/fleet/contact-us")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
}
```

}

Please help as I have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Test classed annotated with [`@WebMvcTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) are tests that focus  **only** on the Spring MVC components : controllers.

So the service field declared in your unit test could not be autowired:

```
@Autowired
private ContactUsService service;
```

So you should mock also this dependency :

```
@MockBean
private ContactUsService service;
```

Note also that as `FleetController`  doesn't have any direct dependency on `FleetRepository`, mocking this bean is not required :

```
@MockBean
private FleetRepository repository;
```

It is even worse as it adds a mock in the context that could create side effect during your test.
**You have to mock only the direct dependencies of the controller under test.**

---

As alternative if you want to mock only some beans and not all which are not controllers, don't use `@WebMvcTest` and instead of use [`@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) that will load the whole context.
Then declare in the test class, the class(es) you want to mock with `@MockBean`.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now!

Comment: Why can't we use `@Mock` from Mockito under `@WebMvcTest`?  I get the same `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException `.

Comment: @Eric Huang Because `@Mock` is a mockito annotation. To allow it to be usable you would need a mockito junit5 extension but in fact you don't want that : you want to keep the `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` to load a spring context while being the possibility to mock beans. You could refer to that other question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200720/difference-between-mock-mockbean-and-mockito-mock

Comment: @davidxxx Thank you for your response.  And much appricated for the link..