# Why @MockBean and @InjectMocks cause BeanCreationException?

Tags: spring, mockito

When I write spring boot test and define service as following:

```
@MockBean
@InjectMocks
private Service service;
```

i got *BeanCreationException: Could not inject field ... cannot have an existing value*
Why ?

Why i cannot have my service mocked and all its autowired fields mocked as well ?

Comment: Why inject something into a mock... That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @M.Deinum, what if there is a bean `A` which depends on bean `B` and I want to mock method `A#method1` to return a mocked value sometimes and other times I want it to return the real value it would return (which logic depends on a mocked bean `B`)? I'd need to inject into mock `B` into mock `A`. How could that be overcomed?

Comment: You cannot inject a mock into a mock

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are combining plain mockito (`@Mock`, `@InjectMocks`) with the spring wrappers for mockito (`@MockBean`). Please take a look at this explanation: [Difference between @Mock, @MockBean and Mockito.mock()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200720/difference-between-mock-mockbean-and-mockito-mock)

Comment: this is good one as an addition, if you are using SpringBoot then preferred to use @MockBean, as the bean will be loaded in application context.