# Mocking Object that returns Java 8 Optional Object with Mockito returns Empty Optional

Tags: java, java-8, mocking, mockito, option-type

I'm attempting to mock an object that returns a Java Optional object with Mockito:

```
SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();
Mockito.when(someSpringJpaRepository.findById(Mockito.any(UUID.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(someObject));
```

When `someSpringJpaRepository.findById(UUID)` is called, it returns `Optional.empty`.

I'm expecting the method `findById()` to return `someObject`.
Any reason why it's returning `Optional.empty` instead?

Here is the method:

```
public UUID saveOrder(OrderDTO orderDto) {

        Order order = new Order();
        if (orderDto.getId() != null) {
            Optional<Order> result = orderRepository.findById(orderDto.getId());
            if (result != null && result.isPresent()) {
                order = result.get(); // existing record

            } else {
                order.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
            }
        } else {
            // new record
            order.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        }

        return order.getId();
    }
```

And here is the Junit:

```
@Test
    public void saveOrderTest(){

        @Autowired
        private OrderApiService orderApiService;
        @Mock
        private OrderRepository orderRepository;

        OrderDTO orderDto = new OrderDTO();
        UUID orderID = UUID.randomUUID();
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setId(orderID);

        orderDto.setId(orderID);
        Mockito.when(orderRepository.findById(Mockito.any(UUID.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(order));
        assertNotNull(orderApiService.saveOrder(orderDto));
    }
```

Comment: Do share the signature of `findById` in the question. If the return type is `Optional<T>` for that method, then your mocking is correct but the expectation is incorrect. If the return type is `T` for the method, then your mocking is incorrect and you might want to change it to `.thenReturn(someObject)`.

Comment: `findById` is the Spring CrudRepository method. I did not override the behavior of this method in the implementation `someSpringJpaRepository`

You can find the documentation here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-

Comment: `findById()` returns `Optional<T>`. You suggested that my expectation is, therefore, incorrect. What should be my expectation in this case? Thanks!

Comment: If the method returns an `Optional<T>`, the expectation should be that it can return `Optional<SomeObject>` in that case. Though if the result is `Optional.empty`, it would still be suspicious to me.

Comment: Yea, it's definitely sketchy! I'm not new to Junit and Mockito so I don't think I have any problems in the code, although I could have made a careless mistake somewhere in the code due to looking at it for a long time. Any suggestions for debugging it?

Comment: Can you show more code? In example how do you call this repository method and how do you set your mock?

Comment: I added some details above!

Comment: Change `@Mock` to `@MockBean`

Comment: That's it! `@MockBean` worked! You are Awesome @ByeBye

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `@Mock` in class is doing nothing. You created a separate instance of `orderRepository` which is not injected into your service class. To inject your mock into context use `@MockBean`

Difference between `@Mock` and `@MockBean` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200720/difference-between-mock-mockbean-and-mockito-mock)

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use spy method

```
Repository spyRepo = Mockito.spy(someSpringJpaRepository);
Mockito.doReturn(Optional.of(someObject)).when(spyRepo).findById(Mockito.any(UUID.class));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!, However, switching from mock to spy yielded with the same result, an empty Optional object!