# Spring Mock repository.count() always return 0

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I have a spring boot project where I'm trying to mock my repository for tests.
I would like my repository.count() to return 30L but it actually always return 0

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DishServiceImpl implements DishService {

    private final DishRepository dishRepository;

    public DishServiceImpl(DishRepository dishRepository) {
        this.dishRepository = dishRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Dish> searchDishes() {

        long countDish = dishRepository.count();

        System.out.println(countDish);
        [...]
    }
}
```

---

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = WhatAreWeEatingApp.class)
@Transactional
public class DishServiceTest{

    @Mock
    private DishRepository dishRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DishService dishService;

    @Test
    public void test(){

        when(dishRepository.count()).thenReturn(30L);
        dishService.searchDishes();

        [...]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You repository mock is never set as dependency to the bean service.
Here you mock in the frame of a running Spring container :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = WhatAreWeEatingApp.class)
```

It is not unit test. So you want to use `@MockBean` from Spring Boot to mock a bean in the container, not `@Mock` from Mockito to mock instances created outside the container.
Don't like auto promotional post but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200720/difference-between-mock-mockbean-and-mockito-mock/44200907#44200907) should help you.

To go further you should not need to run a container to test the service method.  So you should probably remove the Spring Boot test annotation and write a real unit test.