# Mocking only specific classes in the action chain

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to write tests in spring java.

Classes i have

```
public class A {

    @Autowired
    private B b;

    public void handle() {
        int xyz = b.call();
    }
}
```

```
public class B {

    @Autowired
    private C c;

    public int call() {
        // Do something else here as well.
        return c.callC();
    }
}
```

```
public class C {

    @Autowired
    private D d;

    public int callC() {
        //do something with d
        return 123;
    }
}
```

I want to actually call the class B but want to mock the response from C.
Don't know whether it's possible or not.

my test

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestA {

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @Mock
    private B b

    @Mock
    private C c

    @Test
    public void mytest() {
        when(c.callC()).thenReturn(1);
        A.handle();
        verify(c, times(1)).callC();
    }
}
```

But it's still actually calling the class C and not mocking it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you have not defined what should happen when `b.call` is executed. this code `when(C.callC())` should be `when(c.callC())`

Comment: @pvpkiran i'll be calling one more class from B and will mock that response as well, so basically i dont want to mock B but i'll mock all the calls which i am making from B.

Comment: but you have mocked B with this annotation here `@Mock
    private B b`

Comment: if you dont want to mock B then Autowire it and not Mock

Answer (score 0):

You’ve got your annotations wrong.
If you want to use SpringRunner / SpringExtension:

- use @MockBean on service you want to mock
- Use @Autowired to inject services that use them

An alternative is to use Mockito runner and @Mock / @InjectMocks

See [Difference between @Mock, @MockBean and Mockito.mock()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200720/difference-between-mock-mockbean-and-mockito-mock)

Comment: and what if i am calling 2 classes from B, and i want to mock one of them and call the other ?

Comment: Let's assume you want to mock C and have real instance of D. Then provide only `@MockBean` of C, and inject `@Autowired` instance of B or D in case you interact with them from your test class. In fact, your code does not reflect its description -  you say "I want to actually call the class B" but you mock it (in an incorrect way).