# Spring MVC Testing with Mock

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I got this unit test code to test my spring mvc view, its look like failing to initialize the service.

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestAppContext.class })
@WebMvcTest
@Transactional
class BillEntryControllerTest {

    
    @Autowired
    private BillEntryService billEntryService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new BillEntryController())
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void checkUpdateBill() throws Exception {
        billEntryService = Mockito.mock(BillEntryServiceImpl.class);

        doNothing().when(billEntryService).addOrUpdateBill(any(BillEntry.class));

        this.mockMvc
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/bill-entry/saveBillEntry").accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        .param("amount", "10.0")
                        .param("owner", "User")
                        .param("property", "Prop")
                        .param("receiptNumber", "ABC")
                        .param("accountName", "AC")
                        .param("billerName", "BN")
                        .param("datePaid", "20/10/2022")
                        .param("dateDue", "20/10/2022"))
                .andExpect(model().errorCount(0)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

And getting following error

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.de.service.BillEntryService.addOrUpdateBill(org.de.model.BillEntry)" because "this.billEntryService" is null
at org.de.controller.BillEntryController.saveBillEntry(BillEntryController.java:157)

```
@PostMapping("/saveBillEntry")
public String saveBillEntry(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("billEntry") BillEntryFormDto dto,
        BindingResult theBindingResult) {
    BillEntry billEntry = new BillEntry();
    if (dto.getBillId()!=null && !dto.getBillId().isEmpty()) {
        logger.debug("biller id " + dto.getBillId());
        billEntry = billEntryService.getBillEntryById(Integer.parseInt(dto.getBillId()));
    }       
    if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        logger.error("has errors ");
        getDefault(model);
        return "bill-entry-form";
    }               
    
    //updating the form attributes      
    billEntry.setAccountName(dto.getAccountName());
    billEntry.setAmount(Double.parseDouble(dto.getAmount().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "")));
    billEntry.setBillerName(dto.getBillerName());
    billEntry.setDateDue(FormatHelper.getDateFromString(dto.getDateDue()));
    billEntry.setDatePaid(FormatHelper.getDateFromString(dto.getDatePaid()));
    billEntry.setProperty(dto.getProperty());
    billEntry.setReceiptNumber(dto.getReceiptNumber());
    billEntry.setOwner(dto.getOwner());
    
    logger.info("attempt to save/update bill entires " + billEntry.getBillId());
    logger.debug("entry  " + billEntry);
//failing at here (line 157)

    billEntryService.addOrUpdateBill(billEntry);
    return "redirect:"+ dto.getRedirect();
}
```

I try to mock the BillEntryService but that didn't help me ether. Any tips on how to fix it or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: (1. `@WebMvcTest` already does `@AutoconfiguteMockMvc`) 2. `@WebMvcTest` and `@Transactional` ...humm?! 3. (main problem) Or you auto-wire (x)or you mock "service". (4. `@BeforeEach` does the same as 1.)

Comment: `TestAppContext` is also relevant/can break/fix much..([edit] post!?;)

Comment: If you want to inject/replace "service" with a mock: (or) use `@MockBean` (with "real context") (x-or) use a mock/no-op `@Bean` in "test context"

Answer (score 0):

This is because your mocked `billEntryService` is not injected into the controller under test. As a result, that field is not initialized (`null`) in the controller during the test.

To fix that, the `billEntryService` must be annotated with [`@MockBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) instead of `@Autowired` in the test. That will inject the mocked version of `BillingEntryService` into the controller. And you shouldn't initialize that mocked `billEntryService` using `Mockito.mock(...)` afterwards. The `mockMvc` shouldn't be initialized either, because you are using `@WebMvcTest` that already injects a proper `mockMvc` and you are autowiring it. So, the `@BeforeEach` method is also to be removed.

Given the above, the relevant part of the test will look like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestAppContext.class })
@WebMvcTest
@Transactional // doesn't seem necessary here but I haven't touched this
class BillEntryControllerTest {

  @MockBean
  private BillEntryService billEntryService;

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void checkUpdateBill() throws Exception {
    doNothing().when(billEntryService).addOrUpdateBill(any(BillEntry.class));
    mockMvc.perform...
  }
```

Also, you can find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44200907/4886722) quite helpful.